# Visual Basic: Image List to Picturebox

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB. I'm trying to put an image of dice in a picture box chosen at random. I have all the pictures in the Image List and I have

```
Dim dice1 As String
  picdice1.Image = DiceImage.Images(dice1)
```

but when I run the program and click the button nothing appears.

Comment: Sorry I did not see your comment. Deleted the answer. I was just hand typing :)

Comment: @Zaggler, `dice1` can be a `String` because `ImageList.Images.Item` will accept either an ordinal index or a text key.  Of course, if you're going to use a text key to retrieve an `Image` then you have to have set a key on that `Image` in the first place.  Also, as you say, if you're going to use `dice1` then it would have to have a value, whether that value be `Integer` or `String`.

Comment: Correct i was saying it was empty in gerneral. Yes it can be accessed by the key or index. My wording was incorrect 